# How to output the offset of a member in a struct at compile time (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

I'm trying to output the offset of a struct member during compile time. I need to know the offset and later I'd like to add an #error to make sure the member stays at the same offset.
There are a couple of ways I saw working methods to do that already in VS, but I'm using GCC and they didn't work properly.

Thanks!

Comment: You should **not need** this. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's a rather large project some of it is written in assembly, I need to make it harder for people to shoot themselves in the foot if they change the location of the member since the offset is hard-coded in the assembly code. If you know a way to find the offset of the struct from the assembly code, that could be another solution - I mean use the offset automatically in the assembly code

Comment: I don't know a solution for doing this at compile time. However, you could throw in a few `assert(offsetof(struct foo, some_member) == 12)`.

Comment: @H2CO3: I see valid use-cases: for example to make sure that the external API remains backwards compatible... if you check projects like ffmpeg, unless it's a major version number change, you're not alloved to add members to the middle of the struct (but you're allowed to add to the end as that doesn't break anything).

Comment: Can you use C11 static assertions?

Comment: I can use C11, I think I have a small lead here: using offsetof to get the offset as a constant and use it when instantiating a template class, so I can get the offset this way if I get a variable to overflow, but I am still not sure how to do the error at compile time...

Comment: Note that in C++, `offsetof` can only be applied to standard layout classes (POD classes, up through C++03).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`offsetof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) macro, along with the C++11 `static_assert` feature, such as follows:

```
struct A {
     int i;
     double db;
     ...
     unsigned test;
};

void TestOffset() {
     static_assert( offsetof( A, test ) == KNOWN_VALUE, "The offset of the \"test\" variable must be KNOWN_VALUE" );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

put this in the same file as your `main()`:

```
template <bool> struct __static_assert_test;
template <> struct __static_assert_test<true> {};
template <unsigned> struct __static_assert_check {};

#define ASSERT_OFFSETOF(class, member, offset) \
    typedef __static_assert_check<sizeof(__static_assert_test<(offsetof(class, member) == offset)>)> PROBLEM_WITH_ASSERT_OFFSETOF ## __LINE__
```

and this inside your `main()`:

```
ASSERT_OFFSETOF(foo, member, 12);
```

That should work even if you don't have C++11. If you do, you can just define `ASSERT_OFFSETOF` as:

```
#define ASSERT_OFFSETOF(class, member, offset) \
    static_assert(offsetof(class, member) == offset, "The offset of " #member " is not " #offset "...")
```